# Does the Forge Viewer support the 3ds Max VRay render engine?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is VRay currently supported or is there any plans to support this render engine in the Forge Viewer?

If not, is there currently any support for any other render engine than the currently supported Scanline render engine?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

VRay is supported according to our 3ds Cloud Engineering and they say there's even special, optimized translation workflow (translating the model to the SVF format for rendering by Forge Viewer) for VRay. Otherwise far as I know we don't have any official support for Prism just yet and there's no plan to add that for the near future.

Comment: thanks! Could you please share with us this optimized translation workflow for this translation? That would have been highly interesting to look into.

Comment: @BryanHuang We would also very much be interested in the VRay workflow. We have tried to translate VRay materials the same way as we do with the Scanline workflow using Postman and zipping the textures but the VRay materials doesn't translate using this workflow as they remain blank without texture in the viewer while the Scanline materials will display.

Comment: @Bryan Would there happen to be any update on this one?